# How do you deploy your play 2 scala applications?

Tags: deployment, cloud, web-deployment, devops, playframework-2.5

I am interested how do you (scala play2 devs) deploy in cloud? Which cloud provider and so on. Because I am not sure I am doing it in easiest way. I used heroku and it was good. Trying now digitalocean and for now deploying by ssh manually(or jenkins). I did not use docker or dokku for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on AWS, CodeDeploy could be a good start for automatic deployments. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started.html)

Comment: Great, I will check it. Already tried Elastic Beanstalk with play2. Want to check OpsWorks and CodeDeploy! Thanks!